# How to avoid involuntary conversion of VB escape character ("") to Javascript (\")

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, vb.net

In a website I am creating, a query is coming from the asp files according to user-specified filters on the client side of the site. The query will always contain some escaped double quotes (for SQL Rules), as VB-style escape is "". However, when I pass this query into a javascript file to run through a mapping Web Service, the escaped double quotes are replaced with the javascript-style escaped quote, which is \" .

When this ends up going through an ajax function to query an oracle DB and plot points on google map, it errors out because the javascript-style escape characters ( \" ) eventually somehow become ( \\" ), which obviously won't be accepted by SQL. Below is a sample test and what I see when debugging.

html hidden input assignment:

```
queryStringInput.Value = commandstr + wherestr
```

Proper query from aspx.vb page (I know this syntax is good, so this is the literal of what I want to show in the js file):

```
"SELECT cf.METERID as ""Meter ID"", REPID as ""Rep ID"", DIVISION as ""Division"", OPCTR as ""Op Center"",  CITY as ""City"", ADDRESS as ""Address"", cf.PREMISEID as ""PremiseID"",  daysOnPrem.premCount as ""Days Bad On Premise"",  premRecurr.premCount as ""Premise Recurrences"",  RATECODE as ""Ratecode"", METERFORM as ""Meter Form"", METERSTATUS as ""Meter Status"", METERPOINTSTATUS as ""Meter Point Status"",  BILLINGCYCLE As ""Billing Cycle"", FILENAME As ""Filename"", FILEDATETIME As ""File Date/Time"", LATITUDE As ""Latitude"", LONGITUDE As ""Longitude"", FAILURETYPE As ""Fail Type"", CURRENTSTATUS As ""Current Status"" from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES cf  join (Select meterid, PREMISEID, count(PREMISEID) As premCount from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES group by meterid, PREMISEID) daysOnPrem On daysOnPrem.meterid = cf.meterid  join (Select premiseid, count(premiseID) As premCount from (Select meterid,PREMISEID, count(PREMISEID) As premCount from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES group by meterid, PREMISEID) group by PREMISEID) premRecurr On premRecurr.premiseID = cf.premiseid  WHERE DIVISION = 'Western' AND FILEDATETIME >= to_date('06012016', 'mmddyyyy')"
```

js command to get above query from html hidden input variable (through testing, I found that this needed to be in double quotes):

```
var queryStringValue = "\"" + document.getElementById('queryStringInput').value + "\"";
```

what actually shows up in the js file in place of the query:

```
\"SELECT cf.METERID as \"Meter ID\", REPID as \"Rep ID\", DIVISION as \"Division\", OPCTR as \"Op Center\",  CITY as \"City\", ADDRESS as \"Address\", cf.PREMISEID as \"PremiseID\",  daysOnPrem.premCount as \"Days Bad On Premise\",  premRecurr.premCount as \"Premise Recurrences\",  RATECODE as \"Ratecode\", METERFORM as \"Meter Form\", METERSTATUS as \"Meter Status\", METERPOINTSTATUS as \"Meter Point Status\",  BILLINGCYCLE As \"Billing Cycle\", FILENAME As \"Filename\", FILEDATETIME As \"File Date/Time\", LATITUDE As \"Latitude\", LONGITUDE As \"Longitude\", FAILURETYPE As \"Fail Type\", CURRENTSTATUS As \"Current Status\" from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES cf  join (Select meterid, PREMISEID, count(PREMISEID) As premCount from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES group by meterid, PREMISEID) daysOnPrem On daysOnPrem.meterid = cf.meterid  join (Select premiseid, count(premiseID) As premCount from (Select meterid,PREMISEID, count(PREMISEID) As premCount from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES group by meterid, PREMISEID) group by PREMISEID) premRecurr On premRecurr.premiseID = cf.premiseid  WHERE DIVISION = 'Western' AND FILEDATETIME >= to_date('06012016', 'mmddyyyy')\"
```

subsequent error message (where you can see the triple-backslashes):

```
"{\"Message\":\"Invalid object passed in, \\u0027:\\u0027 or \\u0027}\\u0027 expected. (38): {queryString: \\\"SELECT cf.METERID as \\\"Meter ID\\\", REPID as \\\"Rep ID\\\", DIVISION as \\\"Division\\\", OPCTR as \\\"Op Center\\\",  CITY as \\\"City\\\", ADDRESS as \\\"Address\\\", cf.PREMISEID as \\\"PremiseID\\\",  daysOnPrem.premCount as \\\"Days Bad On Premise\\\",  premRecurr.premCount as \\\"Premise Recurrences\\\",  RATECODE as \\\"Ratecode\\\", METERFORM as \\\"Meter Form\\\", METERSTATUS as \\\"Meter Status\\\", METERPOINTSTATUS as \\\"Meter Point Status\\\",  BILLINGCYCLE As \\\"Billing Cycle\\\", FILENAME As \\\"Filename\\\", FILEDATETIME As \\\"File Date/Time\\\", LATITUDE As \\\"Latitude\\\", LONGITUDE As \\\"Longitude\\\", FAILURETYPE As \\\"Fail Type\\\", CURRENTSTATUS As \\\"Current Status\\\" from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES cf  join (Select meterid, PREMISEID, count(PREMISEID) As premCount from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES group by meterid, PREMISEID) daysOnPrem On daysOnPrem.meterid = cf.meterid  join (Select premiseid, count(premiseID) As premCount from (Select meterid,PREMISEID, count(PREMISEID) As premCount from COMMUNICATION_FAILURES group by meterid, PREMISEID) group by PREMISEID) premRecurr On premRecurr.premiseID = cf.premiseid  WHERE DIVISION = \\u0027Western\\u0027 AND FILEDATETIME \\u003e= to_date(\\u002706012016\\u0027, \\u0027mmddyyyy\\u0027)\\\", connectionString: \\\"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=luvP1ck3ym0u#s;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=amiop;Data Source=pnhar200\\\"}\",\"StackTrace\":\"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.ArgumentException\"}"
```

So, what is the workaround here to keep the formatting from the VB file behind, rather than have the javascript file reformat the escape characters?

Comment: Turns out Json.stringify does work. It seemingly re-escapes the characters used in the escaped phrase, which makes it appear that there are way too many characters added, but it comes back correct.